# Vim: Remapped keys not working as expected

Tags: vim, clojure

I am using `fireplace.vim` to edit clojure files. When I hit `cpr` in a `clojure.test` file, the tests are run and a window is displayed if there are any failures.

I've defined a map in my `.vimrc` that saves a file, reloads all file dependencies, and runs the `cpr` command. It looks like this:

```
nnoremap cpr :Require!<cr>:w<cr>cpr
" I have also tried using nmap
```

If I break some of my `src` code and type out the three commands, they work as expected—a window appears detailing my now-failing tests.

But when I try to use the custom keymapping, the `Require!` command does not seem to fire, as no test window appears. What might be causing my keymapping to fail?

Comment: 1. Use `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` if you want to use another mapping in your mapping. 2. Choose another shortcut, `cpr` is already taken.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, this is it. Is there any way of rebinding `cpr` (obviously losing the existing shortcut)?

Comment: If not, I'm happy to accept your existing comment as an answer.